# DGV doesn't update value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I Inerted a DGV called `MarksDGV1` into my application while each cell inside of it has a default value of "0". So, after the user changes the value of some of them, when I try to reach the value for the last edited cell it gives me 0 instead of what the user typed even though it's shown correctly
(**Please note:** the unselected cells -which doesn't appear in Blue color- show value correctly)
How could I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
MarksDGV1.Refresh();
MessageBox.Show(MarksDGV1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

And this is How I built the DGV:

```
        using (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tmp = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn())
        {
            tmp.Width = 90;
            tmp.ReadOnly = true;
            tmp.HeaderText = "פרק מס.";
            MarksDGV1.Columns.Add(tmp);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            using (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tmp = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn())
            {
                tmp.Width = 50;
                tmp.HeaderText = "שאלה מס." + i;
                MarksDGV1.Columns.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            using (DataGridViewRow tmp = (DataGridViewRow)MarksDGV1.Rows[i].Clone())
            {
                tmp.Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
                for (int j = 1; j <= 30; j++)
                {
                    tmp.Cells[j].Value = 0;
                    //tmp.Cells[j].Value = CurrentExam.Psy[i].Answers[j - 1];
                }
                MarksDGV1.Rows.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
```

**Update:** I tried typing `DataGridView.Refresh();` but didn't work!
Update2: I was able to fix this by selecting another cell -different from the one that I'm concerned in- before I get the values. But that's not a solution for me

Comment: Try setting the DataSource to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt (or what ever the source actually is)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have Updated my post, Thanks.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra I have Updated my post, Thanks.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't use a data source to build my DGV

Comment: What event are you calling that code?

Comment: @LarsTech creating the DGV when loading the form, and the rest when the user clicks a button

Comment: Side note: even though your code works, the using-block is meant to dispose the object at the end of the block.  I would remove those, since you aren't disposing them.

Comment: @LarsTech why I am not disposing, when the using block ends it disposes them automatically.

Comment: The code you posted does not duplicate the problem.  I enter a 4 in the second column, press the button, the message says "4".  Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @LarsTech what's may cause it? please it's urgent

Comment: @LarsTech the problem is caused when the courser stays inside that cell, not when it's selected

Comment: Doesn't the cursor leave when you click on the button?

Comment: @LarsTech No, it doesn't

Comment: A button gets focus when you click on it.  Why is yours different?

Comment: yeah that's the problem, I'm using different buttons! i tried to use the traditional one and everything was fixed. Please, give me a way to fix that with these buttons and submit it as answer

Comment: How am I supposed to know what buttons you are using?  Is it a ToolStripButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are using a button that doesn't take the focus away from the grid, so it remains in edit mode.  Try it like this:

```
MarksDGV1.EndEdit();
MessageBox.Show(MarksDGV1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked another solution is to use .Focus();